# Query a view doesn't works with DBFlow

Tags: android, database, orm

I'm using DBflow to query an SQLite database containing several tables. Since my query contains a lot of joins it's kind of difficult to read using the DBflow join :

```
SQLite.select()
.from(Plant.class).as("p0")
                .innerJoin(Definition.class).as("d0")
                    .on(Plant_Table.definitionId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("p0").build()).eq(Definition_Table.definitionId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("d0").build())))
                .innerJoin(Picture.class).as("pi0")
                    .on(Plant_Table.pictureId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("p0").build()).eq(Picture_Table.pictureid.withTable(NameAlias.builder("pi0").build())))
                .innerJoin(SpaceAssociation.class)
                    .on(Plant_Table.pictureId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("p0").build()).eq(SpaceAssociation_Table.plantId1))
                    .innerJoin(Plant.class).as("p1")
                        .on(SpaceAssociation_Table.plantId2.eq(Plant_Table.plantId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("p1").build())))
                        .innerJoin(Definition.class).as("d1")
                            .on(Plant_Table.definitionId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("p1").build()).eq(Definition_Table.definitionId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("d1").build())))
                        .innerJoin(Picture.class).as("pi1")
                            .on(Plant_Table.pictureId.withTable(NameAlias.builder("p1").build()).eq(Picture_Table.pictureid.withTable(NameAlias.builder("pi1").build())))
                    .innerJoin(Flag.class)
                        .on(SpaceAssociation_Table.flagId.eq(Flag_Table.flagId))
                        .innerJoin(FlagDefinition.class)
                            .on(Flag_Table.flagDefinitionId.eq(FlagDefinition_Table.flagDefinitionId));
```

So I decided it would be a better idea to create a SQL view in my database and query this view :

```
SQLite.select()
    .from(PlantsAssociations.class)
    .queryList();
```

Far more readable ! The problem is that I'm getting this error

> database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PlantsAssociations (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `PlantsAssociations`

If I copy and paste this generated query and execute it directly in SQLite console on my database it works...

[image]

I check the [official documentation](https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/Usage.html), it says "Declared like tables" :

> Views: Declared like tables, Views (Virtual Tables) are supported.

So I declared my view exactly like a table :

```
@Table(database = PlantsDatabase.class)
public class PlantsAssociations extends BaseModel {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(name = "p0_plant_id")
    private int p0PlantId;

    @Column(name = "p0_definition")
    private String p0Definition;

    @Column(name = "p0_picture")
    private String p0Picture;

    @Column(name = "p1_plant_id")
    private int p1PlantId;

    @Column(name = "p1_definition")
    private String p1Definition;

    @Column(name = "p1_picture")
    private String p1Picture;

    @Column(name = "flag_id")
    private int flagId;

    @Column(name = "flag_definition")
    private String flagDefinition;

    public PlantsAssociations() { }

    public PlantsAssociations(int p0PlantId, String p0Definition, String p0Picture, int p1PlantId, String p1Definition, String p1Picture, int flagId, String flagDefinition) {
        this.p0PlantId = p0PlantId;
        this.p0Definition = p0Definition;
        this.p0Picture = p0Picture;
        this.p1PlantId = p1PlantId;
        this.p1Definition = p1Definition;
        this.p1Picture = p1Picture;
        this.flagId = flagId;
        this.flagDefinition = flagDefinition;
    }

    public int getP0PlantId() {
        return p0PlantId;
    }

    public void setP0PlantId(int p0PlantId) {
        this.p0PlantId = p0PlantId;
    }

    public String getP0Definition() {
        return p0Definition;
    }

    public void setP0Definition(String p0Definition) {
        this.p0Definition = p0Definition;
    }

    public String getP0Picture() {
        return p0Picture;
    }

    public void setP0Picture(String p0Picture) {
        this.p0Picture = p0Picture;
    }

    public int getP1PlantId() {
        return p1PlantId;
    }

    public void setP1PlantId(int p1PlantId) {
        this.p1PlantId = p1PlantId;
    }

    public String getP1Definition() {
        return p1Definition;
    }

    public void setP1Definition(String p1Definition) {
        this.p1Definition = p1Definition;
    }

    public String getP1Picture() {
        return p1Picture;
    }

    public void setP1Picture(String p1Picture) {
        this.p1Picture = p1Picture;
    }

    public int getFlagId() {
        return flagId;
    }

    public void setFlagId(int flagId) {
        this.flagId = flagId;
    }

    public String getFlagDefinition() {
        return flagDefinition;
    }

    public void setFlagDefinition(String flagDefinition) {
        this.flagDefinition = flagDefinition;
    }
}
```

But as said before it looks like DBflow generate the right query but there is something wrong by finding the view on SQLite side....

So I checked the official [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) and it looks like I did it right :

```
CREATE VIEW PlantsAssociations
as
select  p0.plantid as p0_plant_id,
    d0.definition as p0_definition,
    pi0.picture as p0_picture,
    p1.plantid as p1_plant_id,
    d1.definition as p1_definition,
    pi1.picture as p1_picture,
    flag.flagId as flag_id,
    flagDefinition.definition as flag_definition
from plant p0
  inner join definition d0
    on p0.definitionId = d0.definitionId
  inner join picture pi0
    on p0.pictureId = pi0.pictureId
  inner join spaceAssociation
    on p0.plantId = spaceAssociation.plantId1
    inner join plant p1
      on spaceAssociation.plantId2 = p1.plantid
 inner join definition d1
        on p1.definitionid = d1.definitionid
      inner join flag
        on spaceAssociation.flagId = flag.flagId
        inner join flagDefinition
          on flag.flagDefinitionId = flagDefinition.flagDefinitionId         
      inner join picture pi1
        on p1.pictureid = pi1.pictureid
where d0.definition != d1.definition
```

Did i missed something ?

**[EDIT]**
I just increased the database version number but now the query just returns me an empty list...

Comment: Did you go on to read [ModelViews](https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/ModelViews.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried ModelViews and got the same result. The biggest problem is that I don't have any error message just an empty result set so it's kind of difficult to figure this out. By the way i use this with an existing database, the view I created is for a better readability of my code and The ModelViews class force me to declare a `@ModelViewQuery` with my view dbflow query (but this view will never be created since it already exists).... so even if I can make it works it doesn't resolve the readybility problem. Maybe using an ORM was not a good choice.

Comment: I think I found part of the solution. When I query the database with SQLite i have a pictureId column in my Plant table. But it looks like DBFlow can't find it **SQLiteException: no such column: pictureid**. Maybe it can't find the View neither, but just say nothing and just return an empty result. But I have no idea why it can't find a column who  exists in database and in my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled the app then `./gradelw clean` and Reintall the app.

it works...